# Not able to set proper border for a <div> having image and text tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wanted to have some text and an image to be displayed in way that the text is at the left and after it follows an image. Like in blogs. So first I made a <div> tag as an container for the text and image. Then I used a <p> tag to enter text and image. I set the **float** property of the image float:right.
Now i got the the text and image in blog like form just the way I wanted.
But i also wanted to add borders to the whole content. So that it looks like the text and image are in a box.
But the border are not able to cover the image's height and width.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Float</title>
</head>
<style>
  img {
    float: right;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>
    <p><img src="https://s27363.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Tigers-Nest-Hike.jpg.optimal.jpg" alt="Tiger's Nest"
        style="width:200px; height:200px; margin-left:15px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem
      egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor
      vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in
      odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed
      ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac...
    </p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display: flex;` to the div:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Float</title>
</head>
<style>
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

  img {
    float: right;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>
    <p><img src="https://s27363.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Tigers-Nest-Hike.jpg.optimal.jpg" alt="Tiger's Nest"
        style="width:200px; height:200px; margin-left:15px;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem
      egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor
      vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in
      odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed
      ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac...
    </p>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```